# Parameterizing a circle of radius r: do we have to use trigonometric functions? Can't we just set $y=\sqrt{9-t^2}$, $z=t$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, circles, parametric

Let's consider a circle traced out on the $yz$-plane by $y=\sqrt{9-z^2}$ (note that  $x=0$).

To parameterize this, wouldn't we simply set $z=t$ and $y=\sqrt{9-t^2}$ ?

For some reason my textbook takes the approach of using trigonometric functions:
[image]

Is there a difference between my solution and the one the textbook shows? If not, is there a reason it choose the less intuitive solution involving trigonometric equations instead of the traditional equation of a circle?

Furthermore, couldn't set $y=-3 $sin$t$ and $z=$cos$t$ and we'd get the same result? Just trying to gain some intuition behind this because I'm not used to circles being expressed using trignometric functions...

Comment: You'll only get a semi-circle since $\sqrt{9-z^2}\ge 0$.

Comment: @Bernard Oh...I somehow wasn't aware of this. Thank you for the help. It's strange that $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ will give you a full circle but simply rearranging that equation gives you the equation of a half circle...from that understanding, does it sound like I'm missing any intuition here?

Comment: You are simply rearranging it but you're narrowing it down while rearranging. You don't preserve the equivalence.

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ is always the non-negative square root.

Comment: Applying the square root is, in my opinion, _not_ "simply rearranging", for precisely the reason that the solution set changes.

Comment: You simply forgot tha a positive number has two square roots, which are opposite, and that the symbol $\sqrt{ \;}$ denotes the nonnegative root. This being said, there does  exist rational parameterisations of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

In general to parameterize a function you can choose $x=t, y=f(t)$. Of course, a circle fails the vertical line test in the plane so it's not a function and this means we must parameterize the circle using another method. This is typically the trig functions or [stereographic projection](http://stereographic%20projection).

Comment: That makes sense and helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your parametric functions are not correct as $\sqrt c$ only returns positive values. You would only get half the circle with your equations.

Trigonometric functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ are used because of their simplicity and how easy it is to work with them. $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are used to describe harmonic motion. A dot tracing a circular path is a superimposition of these two harmonic functions.

Putting $+/-$ in front of $\sin$ and $\cos$ wont change the shape drawn. It will only affect the starting point and direction(clockwise or anti clockwise) of the point.

I suggest you plot the trigonometric functions in something like desmos and play around a little. It will give you an intuitive sense of how they describe the circle. Plot $x={\cos t}$ and $y={\sin t}$ separately. Play around with the slider for $t$. Then plot the point 
$A({\cos t},{\sin t})$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wish I'd known about Desmos earlier haha...